# About Time.time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a stopwatch in one scene (stage_A) of my game. When I start the scene (menu) the timer in this scene (stage_A) starts counting and I am unable to find out why. I want it to begin counting only when the scene (stage_A) is loaded. The following is my code:

script stage_A on Main Camera:

```
public Text stopwatch;

void Update () 
{
 if(Application.loadLevel != 1)
   return;

  //Display format 00:00
  var secs = (int)(Time.time % 60);
  var mins = (int)(Time.time / 60);

 stopwatch.text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", mins, secs);
}
```

script Menu:

```
public void Play()
{
   StartGame.current = new StartGame();
   StartGame.current.Character.name = name;
   SaveLoad.Save();
   Application.LoadLevel("stageA");   
}
```

In build settings the index scene menu is 0 and scene stage_A is 1.

solution:

```
  if (startTime == 0.0)
        startTime = Time.time;
    else 
    {
        secs = (int)((Time.time % 60) - startTime);
        mins = (int)(Time.time / 60);
        txttempo.text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", mins, secs);
    }
```

Correction:
after some tests I realized that when the variable `secs` reached " 00:57 " the stopwatch redo the count again subtracting the value contained in `startTime` , after one look again got an answer to the following code:

```
 timer += Time.deltaTime;

 mins = Mathf.FloorToInt(timer / 60F);
 secs = Mathf.FloorToInt(timer - mins * 60);
 stopwatch.text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", mins, secs);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Docs for [`Time.time`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html) say:

> This is the time in seconds since the start of the game.

So I'm not sure why you expected it to give you seconds since the stage loaded.  You'll need to save the value on the first frame that you want it to start, then in your update subtract the saved value from the current value of `Time.time`.  This will give you a stopwatch effect.

Something like:

```
private float startTime = 0.0F;
void Update () 
{
 if(Application.loadLevel != 1)
   return;

  if(startTime == 0.0) startTime = Time.time;
  var counter = Time.time - startTime;
  //Display format 00:00
  var secs = (int)(counter % 60);
  var mins = (int)(counter / 60);

 stopwatch.text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", mins, secs);
}
```